# Is there a Python equivalent to R's sample() function?

Tags: python, r, probability

I want to know if Python has an equivalent to the `sample()` function in R.

The [sample()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) function takes a sample of the specified size from the elements of x using either with or without replacement.

The syntax is:

```
sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
```

(More information [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html))

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think `numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)` may well be what you are looking for.

The `p` argument corresponds to the `prob` argument in the `sample()`function.

Answer (score 10):

In [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (Python's closest analogue to R) there are the [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and [`Series.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.sample.html) methods, which were both introduced in version 0.16.1.

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  6
1  2  7
2  3  8
3  4  9
4  5  0
```

Sampling 3 rows without replacement:

```
>>> df.sample(3)
   a  b
4  5  0
1  2  7
3  4  9
```

Sample 4 rows from column 'a' with replacement, using column 'b' as the corresponding weights for the choices:

```
>>> df['a'].sample(4, replace=True, weights=df['b'])
3    4
0    1
0    1
2    3
```

These methods are almost identical to the R function, allowing you to sample a particular number of values - or fraction of values - from your DataFrame/Series, with or without replacement. Note that the `prob` argument in R's `sample()` corresponds to `weights` in the pandas methods.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `random` package works. Specifically random.sample().

[here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the function you propose does not offer the possibility of random sampling with replacement. The functions @ajcr and I propose can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers here are great, but I'd like to mention an alternative from Scikit-Learn that we can also use for this, [see this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.resample.html).

Something like this:

```
resample(np.arange(1,100), n_samples=100, replace=True,random_state=2)
```

Gives you this:

```
[41 16 73 23 44 83 76  8 35 50 96 76 86 48 64 32 91 21 38 40 68  5 43 52
 39 34 59 68 70 89 69 47 71 96 84 32 67 81 53 77 51  5 91 64 80 50 40 47
  9 51 16  9 18 23 74 58 91 63 84 97 44 33 27  9 77 11 41 35 61 10 71 87
 71 20 57 83  2 69 41 82 62 71 98 19 85 91 88 23 44 53 75 73 91 92 97 17
 56 22 44 94]
```