# Unexpected behavior when using R sample function with rpy2?

Tags: python, r, random, rpy2

I need to cross-validate an `R` code in `python`. My code contains lots of pseudo-random number generations, so, for an easier comparison, I decided to use `rpy2` to generate those values in my `python` code "from `R`".

As an example, in R, I have:

```
set.seed(1234)
runif(4)
[1] 0.1137034 0.6222994 0.6092747 0.6233794
```

In python, using `rpy2`, I have:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
set_seed = robjects.r("set.seed")
runif =  robjects.r("runif")
set_seed(1234)
print(runif(4))
[1] 0.1137034 0.6222994 0.6092747 0.6233794
```

as expected (values are similar). However, I face a strange behavior with the `R` `sample` function (equivalent to the `numpy.random.choice` function).

As the simplest reproducible example, I have in `R`:

```
set.seed(1234)
sample(5)
[1] 1 3 2 4 5
```

while in `python` I have:

```
sample =  robjects.r("sample")
set_seed(1234)
print(sample(5))
[1] 4 5 2 3 1
```

The results are different. Could anyone explain why this happens and/or provide a way to get similar values in R and python using the R `sample` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the value of the R function `RNGkind()` in both situations, I suspect you won't get the same answer. The Python result looks like the default output, while your R result looks like the old buggy output.

For example, in R:

```r
set.seed(1234, sample.kind = "Rejection")
sample(5)
#> [1] 4 5 2 3 1
set.seed(1234, sample.kind = "Rounding")
#> Warning in set.seed(1234, sample.kind = "Rounding"): non-uniform 'Rounding'
#> sampler used
sample(5)
#> [1] 1 3 2 4 5
set.seed(1234, sample.kind = "default")
sample(5)
#> [1] 4 5 2 3 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So it looks to me as though you are still using the old "Rounding" method in your R session.  You probably saved a workspace a long time ago, and have reloaded it since.  Don't do that, start with a clean workspace each session.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this a shot (stackoverflow answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077204/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rs-sample-function)). Quoting the answer : "The p argument corresponds to the prob argument in the sample()function"

```
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)
```